# Error connecting OpenXava to SQL Server - It was impossible to execute the Record action: [Persist

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, openxava

I want to connect OpenXava with SQL Server 2019 (15.0.2104), however, enabling that option in context and persistence gives me an error. When I run the program it does give me the address to the page and I can write information, however, when I click on the "record" button I get the error:

> It has been impossible to execute the Record action: [PersistenceUnit: default ] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Do you know how to fix it?

I enable the TCP IP option from the SQL Server configuration And I create the database and the user with its login.

Here is the project: https://github.com/solee2222/CLINIC.git
(Clone it with git)

I have this in my persistence.xml file:

```
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="123"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=facturaciondb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
```

This in my context.xml file

```
    <!-- Microsoft SQL Server -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/facturacionDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxTotal="20" maxIdle="5" maxWaitMillis="10000"
          username="user" password="123" 
          driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

And finally this in my pom.xml file

```
        <!-- Microsoft SQL Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.1.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: _SQL Server Management Studio_ is not a database server, it's a tool for managing database servers. What version and edition of Microsoft SQL Server do you have installed? What's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` when executed against it?

Comment: You need to add a bit more info, for example the whole error.

Comment: If possible, might you share your minimum sample project without any sensitive code for that problem? I agree with siggemannen that the whole log is helpful.

Comment: You don't need to put the connection details in persistence.xml given that they are already in context.xml. persistence.xml should have the datasource jndi name. Look at the doc for an example. Morever, we need the stacktrace to see the cause of the error.

Comment: https://github.com/solee2222/CLINIC.git                    @JackyLiu-JetBrains